# FirebaseUI user null after signin

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

After choosing my Google account to sign in, the **user** is returning null. Using the Firebase Console I can see that users get authenticated and I can see it on localstorage.

[image]

I've been at this for a while now and any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

MY SETTINGS

```js
const uiConfig = {
  signInSuccessUrl: '/',
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
  ]
}

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
const uiApp = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())

export { uiConfig, uiApp, app }
```

THE UI

```js
mounted() {
    uiApp.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig)
  }
```

COMMITTING USER

```
authCheck ({ commit }) {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          commit('setUser', user)
          console.log(user)
        } else {
          console.log('no user')
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that the code you shared triggers that error. None of it shows calls to `setAttribute`, `hasAttribute`, or `childNodes`.

Comment: Thanks @frank. Everything else I'm doing is generic. Let me share that...

Comment: The errors were triggered by Chrome extensions (I think) because I'm not getting anything on other browsers. I'm still getting a null currentUser even though I see them on Firebase Authentication Console. I'm keeping it as vanilla as possible and not doing anything with it except console logging it.